# Office365 Group and Planner

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, office-365-groups, microsoft-planner

I have created a SharePoint online site with Teams connected to this site; I have created a Planner and added the Planner SharePoint web part so members can work with the Planner on the SharePoint online site.

I want to give read/view access to other users to view the Planner. Please help me with how to achieve this.

Comment: You may need to mark this Plan as public so that other users having visitor permissions in SharePoint can view the plan added on site page (I haven't tested it personally).

Comment: So, you want people who aren't members of the team to be able to read, but not modify the contents of the plan?

Comment: @GaneshSanapThats correct, I want them to see the planner but not to be able to edit it.